# Sample from a posterior distribution with Metropolis Hastings in R

Tags: r, algorithm

Given some data  from my example i have to sample `(a,b)` from a posterior distribution.

I have to apply  **Metropolis Hastings Algorithm** in order to derive  the values of  `(a,b)`  from the posterior distribution and  then estimate their means.

In the algorithm below i have used as proposal-distribution a bivariate standard normal.

My problem is that because of the exp in the  posterior distribution the algorithm  converges to `(0,0)`.

Can anybody  help me find any mistake in my algorithm  ? I have written the algorithm in R.

```
library('MASS')

library("tmvtnorm")



#Posterior distribution#
#p(a,b|x,y)= prod ((exp(a+b*x))^y)/(1+exp(a+b*x))* exp(-exp(a/β)) 
*exp(15.043)#


#damages#
y=c(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0)

#temperatures#
x=c(53,57,58,63,66,67,67,67,68,69,70,70,70,70,72,73,75,75,76,76,78,79,81)

β=6078083.56 

S=0
s= matrix(data = c(1,0,0,1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = FALSE)
m=c(0,0)

z=0
z=matrix(c(rep(0,20000)),nrow=10000,ncol=2) #z=(a,b)#

for(i in 2:10000)
{

w=rmvnorm(1,mean=m,sigma=s) #Proposol-distibution#
u=runif(1,0,1)

k=dmvnorm(z[i-1,],mean=m,sigma=s)
f=dmvnorm(w,mean=m,sigma=s)

l=prod(((1+exp(z[i-1,1]+z[i-1,2]*x))*
(exp(w[1]+w[2]*x))^y)/((1+exp(w[1]+w[2]*x))*(exp(z[i-1,1]+z[i-1,2]*x))^y))

q=exp(exp(-(w[1]/β))-exp(-(z[i-1,1]/β)))  

a1=k/f
a2=a1*l*q
h=min(1,a2)
if(u<=h)
{z[i,]=w}

else 
    z[i,]=z[i-1,]
}


a_bar=sum(z[,1])/10000
b_bar=sum(z[,2])/10000
```

Comment: work on the log scale and exponentiate in the end, to obtain the acceptance prob.

Comment: I tried this technique but the quantities  `l` and `q` continue to converge to `0`.